# Android DatePicker Text not visible

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I am using android DatePicker with below code,

```
<DatePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:calendarTextColor="@color/appColor"/>
```

but the date text is not visible. See the attached image below,
[image]

I have these entries inside app theme style element,

```
<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@android:style/Widget.DatePicker</item>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem inside a DialogFragment with the default date picker.
However I was opening the datepicke programmatically.

I solved it changing the Context i pass to him, so in your case I think u need to set the context inside the layout. Setting the context of the activity.
( es: tools:context=" blablabla.mycontext.blablabla" ) <- in main Layout

If you are already using the activity's context I don't know how to solve this. 
Good luck ;)